# How to start freecell, installed from software center

Tags: command-line, software-center, 13.04, games

Freecell Solitarire won't load on Ubuntu 13.04. In the software center it appears as Installed but doesn't appear in Search.

Uninstalling and reinstalling did not help.

As a workaround,  would it be possible to start FreeCell from Terminal and then make a shortcut on it to my desktop.

What command do I use to start a prrogram/application from Terminal? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Search for Sol in dash ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fd6mz.png) Once it opens, click on game, and choose select game. when it opens navigate to freecell, and select it. ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Wikn1.png) ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/FqDFi.png) ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/2QOCA.png) ![enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8uWu.png) Or start it from terminal as the bkd.online stated in his answer.

Comment: great, thanks. I remembered that there was a drop down somewhere, but I couldn't find it.

Answer (score 7):

Search for Sol in dash

[image]

Once it opens, click on game, and choose select game. when it opens navigate to freecell, and select it.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Or start it from terminal as the bkd.online stated in his answer.

Answer (score 5):

Command line command is `sol` or `/usr/games/sol`.